# Why did Christine Daae faint after seeing a female statue?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-phantom-of-the-opera

In **Phantom of the Opera**

[image]

Christine Daae faints into Phantom's arms.(below)

[image]

Why would a statue provoke such a reaction?

Comment: Can anyone find a picture of the statue?  Maybe it looks just like Christine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only seen the movie once, because I prefer the musical, but the only fainting I remember is when Christine sees that the phantom has a doll looking at lot like Christine and wearing what looks like a wedding dress. My understanding is that seeing it gives Christine a look at what her future will look like if the phantom gets his way, and as that is shocking to her she faints.

Comment: If we go by the OP's screen caps, she is already wearing a wedding dress herself by that point (?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Christine is not wearing a _wedding_ dress at this point, just _a_ dress.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the first time she meets this guy who she barely knows and he already shows her a life sized doll who looks exactly like her wearing a wedding dress. She's just really shocked to see this (and maybe a little creeped out?). (This isn’t shown in the movie, but in the musical the doll can move, that’s when she faints).
Second, it’s the 18th/19th century and it’s a period drama, it’s gonna be dramatic.

But seriously, it's really not that deep, she's just in shock.